# Parsing Indexed XML in Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing

How do I go about parsing a local XML file to be able to put its string values in the `TextView.setText(String)` method? My local XML file looks something like this:

```
<quran>
<sura index="1" name="الفاتحة">
    <aya index="1" text="In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful."/>
    <aya index="2" text="[All] praise is [due] to Allah, Lord of the worlds -"/>
    <aya index="3" text="The Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful,"/>
    <aya index="4" text="Sovereign of the Day of Recompense."/>
    <aya index="5" text="It is You we worship and You we ask for help."/>
    <aya index="6" text="Guide us to the straight path -"/>
    <aya index="7" text="The path of those upon whom You have bestowed favor, not of those who have evoked [Your] anger or of those who are astray."/>
</sura>
<sura index="2" name="البقرة">
    <aya index="1" text="Alif, Lam, Meem."/>
    <aya index="2" text="This is the Book about which there is no doubt, a guidance for those conscious of Allah -"/>
    <aya index="3" text="Who believe in the unseen, establish prayer, and spend out of what We have provided for them,"/>
    <aya index="4" text="And who believe in what has been revealed to you, [O Muhammad], and what was revealed before you, and of the Hereafter they are certain [in faith]."/>
    <aya index="5" text="Those are upon [right] guidance from their Lord, and it is those who are the successful."/>
```

I want to be able to access specific **text** strings located at specific ayh index numbers but I'm not sure how to do it since for every aya object within a sura object there are two things, the index and the text which I want to access. Please help!

Comment: Any idea how I go about it specifically for this file or a good tutorial? I need to be able to access one string at a time, kind of like search. The user enters the location and the string there is placed in TextView.

Comment: I like [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/). It goes over all the common parsers and compares them all so you'll know which is the right one for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do want to use the `XmlPullParser`, as Harsh suggests, look at the example given in the Class Overview in the [docs][1].

It's "text" attribute in "aya" elements that you want so you should use the method`XmlPullParser.getAttributeValue(null, "text")`, as below:

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( "<quran><sura index=\"1\" name=\"الفاتحة\"><aya index=\"1\" text=\"In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful.\"/><aya index=\"2\" text=\"[All] praise is [due] to Allah, Lord of the worlds -\"/><aya index=\"3\" text=\"The Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful,\"/><aya index=\"4\" text=\"Sovereign of the Day of Recompense.\"/><aya index=\"5\" text=\"It is You we worship and You we ask for help.\"/><aya index=\"6\" text=\"Guide us to the straight path -\"/><aya index=\"7\" text=\"The path of those upon whom You have bestowed favor, not of those who have evoked [Your] anger or of those who are astray.\"/></sura><sura index=\"2\" name=\"البقرة\"><aya index=\"1\" text=\"Alif, Lam, Meem.\"/><aya index=\"2\" text=\"This is the Book about which there is no doubt, a guidance for those conscious of Allah -\"/><aya index=\"3\" text=\"Who believe in the unseen, establish prayer, and spend out of what We have provided for them,\"/><aya index=\"4\" text=\"And who believe in what has been revealed to you, [O Muhammad], and what was revealed before you, and of the Hereafter they are certain [in faith].\"/><aya index=\"5\" text=\"Those are upon [right] guidance from their Lord, and it is those who are the successful.\"/></sura></quran>" ) );
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "Start document");
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "Start tag "+xpp.getName());
        if(xpp.getName().equals("aya")){
            Log.i(getClass().getName(), "aya text: " + xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "text"));
        }
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "End tag "+xpp.getName());
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "Text "+xpp.getText());
    }
    eventType = xpp.next();
}
Log.i(getClass().getName(), "End document");
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution helped me get there! Sorry had been away for a 'long' while. :)